How to avoid excel picture in cell value being overwritten?
I have a template file with several tabs and automation with some formatted designated merged cells for placing pictures.
I've written a macro which removes all the ActiveX controls, UI tabs and calculations through a loop with cell.Value2 = cell.Value2
I have noticed that each picture disappears after this step, and the cells display #VALUE.
While trying to troubleshoot and to find a bypass to skip these cells from the loop I have noticed when a cell with a picture in it is selected, the formula bar displays the text "Picture". When I click in the formula bar, the cell also switches to displaying the text "Picture", while the actual picture disappears.
I've attempted to see what value or value2 these cells return, but VBA returns a type mismatch error.
I would like to keep using the picture in cell format, as it allows to quickly get the picture jumped out for enlarging, then placing it back to the original cell, opposed to the manual drag resize alternative a normal pasting would result. The final goal would be to stop the pictures disappearing after the value2 overwrite loop.
Does anyone know a solution to this problem?

Exactly how did you place the pictures on the sheet?

Copying the image file (appearantly the option only comes up when opening the picture and copying that, and not when copying the picture file directly from a file explorer), then selecting the option "Paste Picture in Cell (C)".

Looks like the VBA object model hasn't been brought up to date to allow you to interrogate if the cell contains a picture. The best I could do is test the cell for the TypeName of the Value ("Error") and the Formula ("Picture"):
If TypeName(ActiveCell.Value) = "Error" And ActiveCell.Formula = "Picture" Then

Nice workaround, I have not used TypeName before. Thanks!
